# Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined error in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**package.json looks like**

```
{
  "name": "react_playlist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "All the course files for the Net Ninja React tutorial playlist on YouTube",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && webpack-dev-server --content-base src/ --inline --hot --port 1234"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-playlist#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

**The error looks like**

> bundle.js:20087 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be
>   null or a function, not undefined
>       at _inherits (bundle.js:20087)
>       at bundle.js:20090
>       at Object. (bundle.js:20115)
>       at **webpack_require** (bundle.js:677)
>       at fn (bundle.js:88)
>       at Object. (bundle.js:14155)
>       at **webpack_require** (bundle.js:677)
>       at module.exports (bundle.js:723)
>       at bundle.js:726

**This is my index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
              <title>React</title>
        </head>

        <body>
      <div id="xyz"></div>
          <script src = "/app/bundle.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**And this is my  index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.component{

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
      <h1>all good</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDom.render(<App />,document.getElementById('xyz'));
```

Comment: There is a typo, it should be `React.Component` with a uppercase `C`

Comment: See this question get a similar error because of the mistake in extending the class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340027/reactjs-super-expression-must-either-be-null-or-a-function/41340331#41340331

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I believe you also added `<App />` to the `ReactDom.render` function, when originally it was not there.

Comment: Also, `ReactDom` should be `ReactDOM` as per your import.

Comment: @NimrodArgov, I just formatted the code and not added anything

Comment: @AndreaFalzetti, Yep that another thing the OP should correct

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri look at the diff.

Comment: @NimrodArgov, it was already there, It just wont show when the code is not formatted ebcause it takes it as a TAG. Similar to when you write <p> in your question and it just doesnt show

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ah, I see, right-o.

Comment: @NimrodArgov I have added this as an answer for you to accept. Credit @ShubhamKhatri/@AndreaFalzetti.

Comment: Probably a few typos in the render() function and the App class - I see `React.Component` is one in the App class, and ReactDOM (*not* ReactDom) - and it looks like you're maybe missing a few `;` as well in the render() function after the `</div>`. Then simply npm run webpack and restart the server - should be good to go then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was because you had `React.component` instead of `React.Component` with an uppercase `C` (@ShubhamKhatri).

Also `ReactDom` should match the case in your import, so it should be `ReactDOM` (@AndreaFalzetti).

**Here is your issue reproduced:**

```js
class App extends React.component{

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
      <h1>all good</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('xyz'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

**Here is your issue fixed:**

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  render(){

    return (
      <div>
      <h1>all good</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('xyz'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="xyz"></div>
```